# disable default sort on grid extjs

Tags: extjs

I want to be able to handle sort event by myself and reload data to the grid, however, I do not want extjs srcipts to re-sort my table after I do, as I already do it on mysql.

How do I disable the default sort and keep the sortchange event triggering?

Setting the column to non sortable doesnt help unfortunately

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorting is controlled by the store, your grid just defers sorting requests back to the store's sorting methods. I haven't had an opportunity to test this but theoretically if you include `sortOnLoad: false` in your store config it won't resort after loading.

As covered [here](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-cfg-sortOnLoad) in the docs.